# How to format a USB flash drive?

Tags: usb-drive, disk-management, disk-formatting

In Windows there is a straightforward "Format" option in a flash drive's right-click pop-up menu. Where's that in Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 has a "Format..." option, when you right-click on the USB drive in Files.

Answer (score 323, accepted):

You can use *Disks*. It's installed by default and easy to use.

[image: Disks application appears in Dash search]

- Click on the Dash icon
- Search for "Disks"
- Click on **Disks**

The application will show up:

[image: choose device in Disks interface left bar]

- 1st: Choose the USB flash drive
- 2nd: Click on the "gear" icon and choose "Format"

This little window will appear, just choose the option you want and click on **Format**:

[image: Erase option, filesystem type option, and Name field shown in Format Volume dialog]

Comment: BTW you will have to unmount first I believe.

Comment: In Ubuntu 14.04, The Disks utility may not select the partition by default--click on the big wide rectangle (it may be called Partition 1), and then the format option will be enabled.

Comment: FWIW, when starting it from the CLI (e.g. in i3), the name is `gnome-disks`.

Comment: I needed this first: https://askubuntu.com/questions/500549/how-to-run-gnome-disk-utility

Comment: Greetings from the future 2020. Hey, this is still valid in 20.04!!!

Answer (score 231):

#### Use *GParted*

[image: GParted screenshot]

[see the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xMYLfhkG-gI)

You can install it

- from Ubuntu Software Center or
- on the command-line:

  ```
  sudo apt install gparted
  ```

## Use the command line

[see the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z6TEh762Vec)

1. To show the USB drive among all storage partitions and volumes on your computer use:

   ```
   lsblk
   ```

   You can also use:

   ```
   df
   ```
2. Suppose it may be `/dev/sdy1`. Unmount it with:

   ```
   sudo umount /dev/sdy1
   ```
3. To format drive with the FAT32 file system format:

   ```
   sudo mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/sdy1
   ```

   To set a file system label for your pen drive in the process:

   ```
   sudo mkfs.vfat -F 32 -n 'name_for_your_pendrive' /dev/sdy1
   ```

   You must include the `-F 32` part to specify the FAT size, it is not 32 by default in ubuntu 19.10. For more info see `man mkfs.fat`.

Comment: It will work even if the usb is write protected. Thanks alot.

Comment: For pen-drive, you don't need the `-I` option, and might prefer to use: `mkfs.fat -v -F 32 -n "MyUsbStick" /dev/sda`.

Comment: To rename a FAT16 or 32 filesystem I am more used to:                                  `sudo mlabel -i /dev/sdy1 ::name_for_your_pendrive`   #(on one line, mind the dobble :)

Comment: GParted is quite useful for Debian as well.

Answer (score 181):

## The Command-Line Way

In case you can't get your device formatted from the GUI, try this way.

1. Open the Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
2. List your block storage devices by issuing the command  `lsblk`
   Then identify your pen drive by it's SIZE. In my case its  `/dev/sdb`

   [image]
3. Erase everything in the pen drive **(This step is Optional)**:

   ```
   sudo dd status=progress if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=4k && sync
   ```

   Replace **`/dev/sdb`** with your corresponding device.

   **Type very carefully this name or your may end up erasing one of your other disks**. This will take some time. (option *status=progress* is not mandatory but provide you some feedback)

   It will pretend to be stuck. Just be patient.

   for example:

   ```
   dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=4k && sync
   dd: error writing '/dev/sdb': No space left on device

   1984257+0 records in
   1984256+0 records out
   8127512576 bytes (8.1 GB) copied, 1236.37 s, 6.6 MB/s
   ```
4. Make a new partition table in the device:

   ```
   sudo fdisk /dev/sdb
   ```

   Then press letter `o` to create a new empty DOS partition table.
5. Make a new partition:

   - Press letter `n`  to add a new partition. You will be prompted for the size of the partition. Making a primary partition when prompted, if you are not sure.
   - Then press letter `w` to  write table to disk and exit.
6. Format your new partition.

   - See your new partition label with the command **`lsblk`**
     In my case it is **`/dev/sdb1`**. *Once again pay attention to this name as there will not be any protection to prevent you to erase an other disk.*

   [image: lsblk output]

   - Issue the command below to format the new volume:

     ```
     sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb1
     ```

     Please replace `/dev/sdb1` with your corresponding device.
   - Eject the device:

     ```
     sudo eject /dev/sdb
     ```

Comment: if you lost patience while waiting for `dd` you can always

`ps aux | grep dd` copy process id then 
`watch -n 4 kill -USR1 pid`

Comment: As opposed to the GUI way it actually properly formats the stick and allows (using the -n <name> parameter) to set the label of that disk. The GUI way doesn't work for me.

Comment: After erasing with the dd command you can try reconnect and do the partition in the GUI itself.

Comment: This is great.  I suggest also doing `sudo apt-get install pmount` - it will take care of the `sync` and remounting at the same location automatically.

Comment: Use `status=progress` as another argument to the `dd` command in step 3. This will give you feedback, so you'll know how the erasion goes.

Comment: Before exiting fdisk (step 5), set the correct partition type by first typing `t` and then choosing hex code `b` for “W95 FAT32”.

Comment: detailed in: https://www.redips.net/linux/create-fat32-usb-drive/

Comment: but instead of type b use type c, or, https://dottheslash.wordpress.com/2011/11/29/deleting-all-partitions-on-a-usb-drive/

Comment: I corrupted a USB drive and am currently going with the terminal way described above to rewrite the partition table. Though: `dd` really is taking A LOT of time. I let it go for all the night, in recovery mode (so the pc was doing just that) and it was able to do 1.8GB only, at 40kb/s - and only because it began, for some reason, to work at 1.5GB. Is there a way to speed it up? It will need weeks of continous work to do all the 32GB of the stick...

Comment: These steps worked for me except the mkfs step. I got the error `mkfs.vfat: /dev/sdb1 contains a mounted filesystem.`  I resolved this error by running `umount /dev/sdb1` before the mkfs command.

Comment: Is it a problem if you use a bigger block, say 4M, for the `dd` command? Definitely speeds up things.

Comment: Maybe you could edit your answer to include the comment of @igor and @Ferroao to **not** use another program but only `fdisk`.

Answer (score 37):

[gparted](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gparted) - the only way to go with formatting drives and HDs etc. It's available for download in the Ubuntu Software Center, just search for *gparted*.

Answer (score 37):

Run the below commands to format the usb to **fat32** filesystem from terminal,

```
sudo su
fdisk -l
```

(this helps  to discover your pendrive /dev/sdxx)

```
umount /dev/sdxx
```

then format your device to FAT32

```
mkdosfs -F 32 -I /dev/sdxx
```

Where "xx" is from the command `fdisk -l` which denotes your usb drive's last letters.

Comment: Before doing the `mkdosfs` you want to first wipe the partition table by using `sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdxx count=24`  -- Same goes for if you intend to use `mkfs` for an EXT file system.

Comment: What's the difference between `sdb` and `sdb1`?  I thought I should use `sdb` because I'm formatting the whole drive, but it turns out `sdb1` works...

Answer (score 13):

**`sfdisk` CLI non-interactive method**

```
echo 'start=2048, type=83' | sudo sfdisk /dev/sdX
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdX1
```

erases all data, and creates a single partition that takes up all USB with an ext4 filesystem.

Choose `X` based on the output of:

```
sudo lsblk
sudo fdisk -l
```

For more detailed description of `sfdisk` see: https://superuser.com/questions/332252/creating-and-formating-a-partition-using-a-bash-script/1132834#1132834

**`fdisk` automation**

It is also possible to do the same as above with:

```
printf 'o\nn\np\n1\n\n\nw\n' | sudo fdisk /dev/sdX
```

but this method is less maintainable than `sfdisk`, which was designed for `Scripting fdisk`, specially if you want to create more complex partition tables.

Answer (score 8):

Here are some instruction :

- Plug your flash drive into an empty USB port and back up any data on the drive. Open the main menu, move your cursor over "Accessories" and then click on "Terminal." At the terminal prompt, type `sudo apt-get install gparted` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Enter your Ubuntu administrator password when prompted and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will download and install GParted, which is an open-source drive partitioning program
- Go to the Ubuntu main menu after the installation is complete, move your cursor over "System," select "Administration" and click "Partition Editor." Enter your administrator password when prompted and click "OK."
- Click on "GParted" in the toolbar. Hover over "Devices" and select your USB flash drive from the list (dev/sdb1, for example). Right-click on the device in the main GParted window and click "Unmount." It may take a few minutes for the device to be unmounted
- Right-click on the device again after it is unmounted and hover over "Format to." Select the desired file system type -- RiserFS, linux-swap, Ext 2, Ext 3, FAT16 or Fat32, for example -- and click "Apply" in the toolbar. Depending on the size of the flash drive, it will take three to four minutes for GParted to complete the process.
- Close GParted after the flash drive is formatted. To mount your USB flash drive, unplug it and then plug it back in. The drive is now ready to store data in the file format you selected.

Answer (score 6):

### Restore a USB drive to a standard storage device

Install and use **mkusb** (mkusb-dus), which can format alias restore a USB drive to a standard storage device (with an MSDOS partition table and a partition with the FAT32 file system). These instructions are also relevant for other drives (**memory cards**, hard disk drives, **HDD**, solid state drives, **SSD**).

If you run standard Ubuntu, you may need an extra instruction to get the repository Universe. (Kubuntu, Lubuntu ... Xubuntu have the repository Universe activated automatically.)

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe  # only for standard Ubuntu

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa  # and press Enter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mkusb mkusb-nox usb-pack-efi
```

See these links with more detailed instructions,

- [mkUSB-quick-start-manual.pdf](http://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/mkusb/mkUSB-quick-start-manual.pdf) or if the link does not work, [this alternate link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=mkUSB-quick-start-manual-12.pdf)
- [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

mkusb version 12 alias mkusb-dus:
[image]

**mkusb wipes the first megabyte as a first step of restoring it**

Sometimes some data are 'tricking' the software to think that the pendrive does not work, even when it is good, and it is enough to wipe the first megabyte to get rid of those data. You may 'look at' the drive with a tool, that does not recognize or understand correctly the structure of the boot system, for example if it was cloned from an iso file.

### What to do if mkusb fails

There are many ways that a USB pendrive can fail. So it is worth trying different things. If mkusb fails, try according to this list,

- On some pendrives and on many memory cards there is a small mechanical switch for write protection, that can toggle between read/write and read-only. You might have set it read-only without intention.
- Reboot the computer and try again to restore or wipe the first megabyte with mkusb.
- Disconnect other USB devices. Sometimes USB devices can disturb the function for each other.
- Try other USB ports and another computer.
- Try another operating system (Windows, MacOS) in another computer.
- If you still cannot wipe the first megabyte of the drive, and the drive is read-only, it is probably 'gridlocked', and the next stage is that it will be completely 'bricked'.

There is a limit, when you have to accept that the pendrive is damaged beyond repair, at least with tools available to normal users like you and me. See this link

[Pendrive lifetime](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13199297#post13199297)

Answer (score 5):

Firstly use `fdisk -l` in order to see usb partition, then if:

```
ext == > mkfs.ext3 /dev/sda1
FAT/FAT32 ==> mkfs.vfat /dev/sda1
```

Note: You must be **root** or using **sudo** to do that.

Answer (score 2):

if you are running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS then you can easily do this. just plug in your usb and in left panel you will see a USB icon. go over there and right click. there will be a option to format it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple way:
In linux system:
use 
     *fdisk* to check which is your usb disk. then use *fdisk sdx*,usually is sdb, to do some operation on your usb disk.

press *o enter* 
press *d enter* to empty your disk.

then you can plug your usb drive to a windows operation system and do the normal format.

Answer (score 1):

I use `Startup Disk Creator`, installed by default, to format my USB drives.

- Open up 'startup Disk Creator' by searching for it in the dash.
- Insert your flash drive, it will be detected automatically.
- Select it (in case you have more than one)
- Press 'Erase Disk'

See screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: @Parto, as an Arabic speaker, the title bar of the window was extremely hard to read because I kept on interpreting the Arabic letters rather than figuring out what those letters are suppose to look like as English characters.. lol

Comment: @Fadi Hahah. It's the 'Pseudo Saudi'  - font. http://www.dafont.com/psuedo-saudi.font

Comment: @Parto lol nice! :D

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem especially after the installation of Ubuntu, my USB drive just became no longer usable. I could only use around 1 GB of my 16 GB USB drive. When I entered `lsblk` command on the command line interface it only showed 1 GB part of the USB available but it did not show the rest 14.5 GB as an unavailable part.

Eventually, I created a partition on my USB by using GParted on Ubuntu. Open GParted and then **GParted -> Devices -> /dev/sdb (14.56 GiB)** in my case. I selected that and then go to **Device -> Create Partition** and then click on **Apply**. After that, I unmounted and mounted back my USB. Then **GParted -> Devices -> /dev/sdb** on my case, and then **Partition -> Format to -> fat32**. I clicked on that and then click on the green tick symbol and then it will format.

The similar command of that format in command line interface is I think `mkfs.fat -F 32 -v -l -n`. That was my case.