# How do I format or partition a read-only USB drive?

Tags: usb, gparted, read-only, disk-formatting

Whenever I try formatting my Sandisk Cruzer Glide 16GB, I get this error message on Gparted.

```
GParted 0.11.0 --enable-libparted-dmraid

Libparted 2.3

Create Primary Partition #1 (ntfs, 14.42 GiB) on /dev/sdc  00:00:00    ( ERROR )

create empty partition  00:00:00    ( ERROR )
libparted messages    ( INFO )

Unable to open /dev/sdc read-write (Read-only file system). /dev/sdc has been opened read-only.
Unable to open /dev/sdc read-write (Read-only file system). /dev/sdc has been opened read-only.
Unable to open /dev/sdc read-write (Read-only file system). /dev/sdc has been opened read-only.
Can't write to /dev/sdc, because it is opened read-only.
Unable to open /dev/sdc read-write (Read-only file system). /dev/sdc has been opened read-only.

========================================
```

How do I disable / delete the read only filesystem? Is my USB corrupted?

Comment: Is `/dev/sdc` being used by the system in anyway? such as mounting  a partition in it during boot with `ro` option. Can you provide the  output of the command `sudo umount -a`?

Comment: Check the stick --- sometime they have a physical read-only switch on them.  Check if you are superuser and if the stick is unmounted.  If all this checks fails, try reporting the lines that appears in `/var/log/syslog` when you plug the stick in. If all else fails, I will suggest to try to zero the device with `dd` --- but it's a last option kind of thing. (And yes, it can be that it's physically damaged. It happens.)

Comment: I'd say bad news  - the drive is broken. I've had same issue with my friend's usb drive. I tried re-formating it, but since filesystem is read-only, `gparted` cannot even open it. And the drive is empty. And it doesn't work on any OS - Mac, windows, Linux

Comment: See this answer to a similar question, https://askubuntu.com/questions/877141/format-the-sd-card-with-dd-command/877144#877144

Comment: This link might also help, https://askubuntu.com/questions/22381/how-to-format-a-usb-flash-drive/911791#911791

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The issue at my case was that it was formatted as Ubuntu live CD. And instead of listing the mounpoint of the USB itself in `/etc/mtab`, the Live-Folder within the USB was listed. Therefore, it was impossible to unmount the USB-drive itself. My solution was to remove the mountpoint of the USB with the command

```
$ sudo rm -rf /media/<name of drive>
```

This had the same effect as unmounting the USB and I was able to use gparted for further steps (formatting etc.)