# Why doesn't Gparted show my USB stick?

Tags: usb, gparted, format

I have a new 16 GB kingston flash pen that I cannot format

Gparted doesn't seem to see it

[image]

It has some windows exe and files on it

[image]

In do not have the `format` option as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/22382/47206) for Nautilus, Thunar or PCManFM

Its properties in Nautilus are

[image]

Comment: There is a menu in Gparted on the right up top just above partitions. You might need to click it and swhich to the device.

Comment: yes that's it. the question is to be merged

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- In Gparted, use the menu in the top-right to select your USB flash drive

[image]

[image]

- Unmount any mounted partitions on the flash drive
- Format the partions

Answer (score 1):

Have you tryed bash command `mkfs`?

```bash
fdisk /dev/sda
mkfs -t vfat /dev/sda1
```

See [formatting usb pen in Linux](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/formatting-usb-pen-in-linux/)

Comment: sda1 is my windows partition :)