# Ubuntu Bootable USB drive

Tags: boot, usb, usb-drive

I have installed the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS using a pen drive.
Firstly I made pendrive into a bootable USB drive which includes Ubuntu .iso file extraction. After using that USB drive in my other laptop and installed on it, I am trying to make my USB drive for using other transfers. But it is not detected by my laptop afterwards. Therefore, neither I am able to use that for other stuffs nor it gets unbootable..

So, give me solution.

Comment: See this - hope it helps:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/22381/how-to-format-a-usb-flash-drive

Answer (score 0):

The MultiSystem Multiboot usb allows you to load multiple iso files on to one usb.
With Multisystem you just have to drag and drop your iso files to a window and that's all.  -

To install MultiSystem Multiboot -

sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://liveusb.info/multisystem/depot all main'

wget -q http://liveusb.info/multisystem/depot/multisystem.asc -O- | 
sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install multisystem