# Sandisk Cruzer Blade not detected and can't be formatted

Tags: mount, disk, usb-drive

My sandisk cruzer blade is not write protected and it is not mounted in ubuntu. I can't even format it using Disks utility in ubuntu.
dmesg | tail info:

```
rishi@rishi:~$ dmesg | tail
[192006.789212] sd 23:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[192006.789217] sd 23:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[192006.789409] sd 23:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[192006.789413] sd 23:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[192006.791486] sd 23:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[192006.791490] sd 23:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[192006.798617]  sdb: sdb1
[192006.799996] sd 23:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[192006.799999] sd 23:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[192006.800001] sd 23:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

sudo fdisk -l info:

```
rishi@rishi:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x7fa47cdf

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048    97656831    48827392   83  Linux
/dev/sda2        97658878   625141759   263741441    5  Extended
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5        97658880   488476671   195408896   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       504299520   625141759    60421120   83  Linux
/dev/sda7       488478720   504295423     7908352   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/sdb: 4004 MB, 4004511744 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 486 cylinders, total 7821312 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x1decc276

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *          63     7821311     3910624+   b  W95 FAT32
```

fsck -n /dev/sdb info:

```
rishi@rishi:~$ sudo fsck -n /dev/sd
sda   sda1  sda2  sda5  sda6  sda7  sdb   sdb1  
rishi-2899@rishi-2899:~$ sudo fsck -n /dev/sdb
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

When i try to format using Disks utility it ends with error message. The error message follows.

```
Error setting partition type after formatting: Error setting partition flags on /dev/sdb1: Command-line `sfdisk --change-id "/dev/sdb" 1 0x0c' exited with non-zero exit status 1: /dev/sdb: No such file or directory

sfdisk: cannot open /dev/sdb read-write
 (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

Can anyone help me.

--edit--
lsusb output:

```
rishi@rishi:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:5801 Broadcom Corp. BCM5880 Secure Applications Processor with fingerprint swipe sensor
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 045: ID 04ca:0061 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0c45:64d2 Microdia 
Bus 002 Device 057: ID 0781:556b SanDisk Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Post output of `lsusb`

Comment: It doesn't automatically mount, but why can't you mount it using  `sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /media/myusbstick`?

Comment: when i try to mount, it says `rishi@rishi:~$ sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /media/usb
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so`

Comment: It seems that you have done so much, once try this: `sudo mkfs.fat /dev/sdb -I`  Exactly, if it works ,then you mount it with your file manager or with mount command

Comment: @looserof7 it just ended as `rishi@rishi:~$ sudo mkfs.fat /dev/sdb -I
mkfs.fat 3.0.26 (2014-03-07)
rishi@rishi:~$`

Comment: Now you mount it using your file manager

Comment: That's it now your Usb is formatted. Now you can use it normally without any problems

Comment: it is not showing my device `rishi@rishi:~$ ls /dev/ | grep sd
sda
sda1
sda2
sda5
sda6
sda7`

Comment: Did you ever manage to fix this? I have the same problem.

Comment: @Lembik I can't fix it yet. If you found a solution please let me know.

Comment: This was a lot easier for me using disks utility https://askubuntu.com/questions/22381/how-to-format-a-usb-flash-drive

Answer (score 4):

I have had some serious problems with my flash drives as well,

I ended up utilizing:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=4096 status=progress
```

where X is your drive. This is for block size issues encountered on usb after a corrupt ubuntu disk creator attempt.

Then used the fdisk to get it cleared.

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sdX
```

Finally I used

```
mkfs.vfat /dev/sdX
```

I'm sure not all of this was necessary but it worked for me.