# How to partition an empty memory card

Tags: partitioning, 20.04

I removed all partitions in a memory card using "Disks" application in Ubuntu. Then I tried to create a partition. But I'm getting an error when doing so:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZYrF.png]

Comment: I doubt we can help you fix it, because that would involve you learning how to program for a number of years, then digging into source code, finding the bug, fixing, patching, recompiling... - all rather complex, time consuming adventures. As a simple workaround, try another program, Gparted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sandisk Cruzer Blade not detected and can't be formatted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771735/sandisk-cruzer-blade-not-detected-and-cant-be-formatted)

Comment: Part-type is MBR or gpt.  You set that only for entire drive like sdb. Then you create partition(s) like sdb1 and format that partition.