# Ubuntu start with USB

Tags: usb

I try to start my Computer with an USB. But I can not choose to start it, as it is said in every where in the internet, I can only choose to install.

I try to start Ubuntu 14.04, currently there is 16.04 running on the computer.

Does anyone have an Idea how I can only start it? Installing is not a problem btw, but not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Give **mkusb** a try, you can install it to 16.04 and use it to install 14.04, Live or Persistent to a USB drive.

It is great for making bootable pendrives with persistence partition, (if desired), and a Windows/Linix accessible partition in the left over space. The pendrive can also be used to install Ubuntu, but this feature is not forced on the user.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb

Answer (score 0):

Try using https://etcher.io/ for Live USB creation.

Answer (score 0):

You must first [format your USB to FAT32](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22381/how-to-format-a-usb-flash-drive).

1. You can make Gnu/Linux Live USB with [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.github.io/).
   When its installed it requires administrative password to run.
   In distribution select: Ubuntu, 14.04_Live

   **Attention!** Choose right drive (USB) for installing Live Ubuntu!
2. Or with the `dd` utility instead.

   First download linux distribution you want to instal. Get the usb device name with `lsblk`.

   [image]

   In this example USB drive is sdc1
   **Attention! Choose right drive!**

   ```
   sudo unmount /dev/sdc1   
   sudo dd bs=4M if=/path/to/your.iso of=/dev/sdc1 && sync
   ```

When it is all finished, reboot computer.

After rebooting, boot from the USB drive. On PCs, this usually involves pressing a button such as <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>F8</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd> immediately after you turn on your computer. If that don't work set the primary boot drive in your BIOS settings to USB. Press <kbd>Delete</kbd> immediately after you turn on your computer to start the BIOS Utility.

When I start from live USB or CD/DVD looks something like this:

[image]