# Sandisk ultra pendrive doesn't show up on the desktop after formatting but it shows in gnome-disks

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb, mount, hard-drive

My pendrive stopped working and then I formatted it with the Disks program.

After that it stopped showing up on the desktop but it is visible on in Disks.

[image: gnome-disks showing the drive]

I then ran `dmesg`:

[image: excerpt of dmesg output]

Comment: Try with mkusb - select 'restore to a standard data storage device'. See this link, https://askubuntu.com/questions/22381/how-to-format-a-usb-flash-drive/911791#911791

Answer (score 0):

I would reformat it using gparted. After that eject an re-insert in the usb port.