# The partitions on my SD card reappear after removing them

Tags: partitioning, gparted, sd-card

I've tried with Disks and GParted. After both the partitions simply reappear with no error:

[image]

I've used `fdisk` with the options `o`, `n`, `t`, `c`, `wq` and it didn't format and gave no error.

I have used Apple Disk Utility and that didn't work.

I have tried erasing the whole disk with this command:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdd bs=1M
```

and the partitions are still there. How can I remove them?

Comment: Memory cards and USB pendrives have the same kind of hardware inside, so the same methods are relevant to both kinds of devices. It seems to me that the [original] partitions are shown also after reboot. If that is the case, I think the drive is 'gridlocked', that the SD card can be read but not written to. It is a first stage of failure. You can find more detailed information via the following links, https://askubuntu.com/questions/22381/how-to-format-a-usb-flash-drive/911791#911791 and http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13199297#post13199297

Comment: I responded with a detailed answer to your other current call, 'hunting your bounty' ;-) , https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/help-me-i-cant-format-my-usb-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035