# How to clean bootable pendrive in Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04

To install Ubuntu 16.04.3 on my laptop, I used my 8GB pen-drive. The installation of OS has done now. I want to clean this bootable pen-drive to use it normally.[I want to clean it completely like we do in GUI.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rp8CN.png)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is with `dd` but you must be careful to specify the device exactly:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX count=1 bs=512
```

This will erase the partition table / MBR (Master Boot Record) making the pendrive empty and ready for reformatting.

Replace `sdX` with `sdc`, `sde`, etc. matching your pendrive letter revealed by `lsblk`.

[Source](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-clearing-out-master-boot-record-dd-command/)

Answer (score 0):

Format your pen-drive using 'Disks' utility in Ubuntu, then you can use it normally. Here is the link for the same : [How to format a USB flash drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22381/how-to-format-a-usb-flash-drive)

Answer (score 0):

An easy and safe method is to restore the USB pendrive to a standard storage device with **`mkusb`**. It will wipe the current partition table and create an MSDOS partition table and a partition with a FAT32 file system.

See the following links,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/wipe](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/wipe)

[image]

There are more details at this link,

[Restore a USB drive to a standard storage device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22381/how-to-format-a-usb-flash-drive/911791#911791)