# Format image usb drive

Tags: usb-drive

I have used and created an image drive to install Ubuntu server 18.04.

I have tried to erase and reformat using Mac utility but It will not do it.

Can someone explain how to do this in a terminal or other software

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a USB flash drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22381/how-to-format-a-usb-flash-drive)

Comment: See this link, [Postrequisites - restore the USB stick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Postrequisites_-_restore_the_USB_stick)

Answer (score 0):

I tried other ask ubuntu answers but they did not work for me. I found an answer at this link which worked for me.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8132218

at the terminal type

Diskutil List

identify your disk to be erased then type:

diskutil eraseDisk free EMPTY /dev/disk4

Then format the disk

diskutil eraseDisk ExFAT USB64 /dev/disk4 where USB4 is the disk name and EXFAT the format