# How do I access a disk that does not appear in my file and folder program?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I recently started using a notebook that has Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

I know this machine has 1TB of storage, but when I open the program to view files and folders it has a total capacity of only 212.6 GB

I imagine then that the 1TB disk is not ready for use. So at the terminal I typed a command to list drives in order to identify partitions

```
sudo lsblk -o model,name,size,fstype,label,mountpoint

MODEL            NAME     SIZE FSTYPE LABEL  MOUNTPOINT
ADATA SU810NS38  sdb    238,5G               
                 ├─sdb4  31,4G swap          [SWAP]
                 ├─sdb2     5G vfat   OS     
                 ├─sdb3 201,3G ext4   UBUNTU /
                 └─sdb1   750M vfat   ESP    /boot/efi
WDC WD10SPZX-75Z sda    931,5G
```

As I understand it is on disk "sda" which is the size of 1TB or close to it

Please, what I want to know is how can I access this disk? How to view and write files to it?

I first tried to create a directory

```
sudo su
mkdir /mnt/mydrive
```

Then mount the disk for use

```
mount /dev/sdba /mnt/mydrive
```

But this error appeared:

```
mount /dev/sda /mnt/mydrive
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

Comment: Use `gnome-disks` or `gparted`

Comment: Thank you @kenn From what I'm researching I need to mount the storage device, right?

Comment: per that output, it appears the disk has no partitions.  Is it empty?  If so, you just need to format the drive.  There is an easy to use GUI utility called Disks (`gnome-disk-utility`).  If the drive has data on it, perhaps it is formatted with a file system that is not compatible with Ubuntu out of the box (HFS+ / exFAT)

Comment: GUI will guide you. In `gparted` there is drop dow list to pick up drives on the upper right. FYI never use Linux tool to manage `NTFS` Windows filesystem.

Comment: Thanks @Nmath I edited the above question and put the steps in trying to mount the disk. Yes it's a new computer, it was turned on today

Comment: The disk needs to be formatted: It needs to have at least one partition with a file system in order to be mounted.  You can do this with [`gparted`](https://gparted.org/) or [Disks](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Disks).  [How to format a disk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22381/how-to-format-a-usb-flash-drive)