# Help me repair my USB pendrive! i am on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: usb

I am on Ubuntu 18.04. I was trying to transfer files using my pendrive , which I previously used to install Ubuntu on my laptop. But later formatted using Android phone.

When I was trying to transfer files (some videos) it got stuck, so I removed the pendrive from USB slot. And then tried to format it using Android phone.

But now the phone could not format it. And when inserted in Ubuntu it showed :

```
Unable to access "device" error mounting /dev/sdb2 at media/pc_name/pendrive_name : wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb2, missing codepage or helper program , or other error.
```

How can I repair my USB?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a USB flash drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22381/how-to-format-a-usb-flash-drive).  If the flash drive is unreadable on any operating system there is a good chance it is dead

Comment: I tried to format your question post as much as possible, correct it if I made a mistake (like for the error displayed)

Comment: Update: I tried a lot of things, something worked , Now , I can mount my pen drive , but I can not delete any items, it says read-only! Any chance of getting help now?

Comment: Quite often when a pendrive gets bricked it becomes read only. This is often the case of high capacity low cost drives reaching their endurance limit. I have a few like that.