# can not format the USB flash with Trojan ( write protected USB)

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount, hard-drive

My USB have had many files with write protected permission and those are some Trojan, so I have tried the belewo methods :

```
sudo hdparm -r0 /dev/sdb1

/dev/sdb1:
 setting readonly to 0 (off)
 readonly      =  0 (off)
```

[image]

and tried this instruction:

```
sudo fsck -n /dev/sdb1
```

And get the below result which is taking many minutes for ending and I stopped it by pressing `ctrl+shift+z`, which could be seen at [here](https://0bin.net/paste/TZF694H9#9VPBWrJUgIMKWL8whNlrfFe8rl2l1NrW8SblSPfcUDm) with more details:

[image]

So I asked here for finding some way to format this strange USB drive.

**Update 1:**

Base of the first comments, I  added the reason for thinking I have one some Trojan in my USB flash Storage :

> Node32 in windows said it have had some Trojan which I don't remember
> its name, another reason for thinking it  has some Trojan it's Chinese
> strange file name because I don't have any chines file on my USB flash
> storage!

**Update 2:**

based of 4th comment, I have tried to use the `mkusb` as said at [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22381/how-to-format-a-usb-flash-drive):

[image]

But it has been failed and get the below errors (more information could be seen [here](https://0bin.net/paste/Mj6DhA6-#c8JosMu6X37dNzUCdZPfbibimePNhbRrf9uRCkRy+Tu)):

[image]

Also, the `mkusb` has failed in formatting the USB flash by selecting the first option, as you can see below:
[image]
Thanks.

Comment: I do not see any info in your question that tells me you have a trojan. Please explain why you think you do.

Comment: Node32 in windows said it have had some Trojan which I don't remember its name, another reason for thinking it  has some Trojan it's Chinese strange file name because I don't have any chines file on my USB flash storage!

Comment: I would not believe any thing a Windows program said about files in a Ubuntu system. Also this comment should be in the question not afterwards as a comment.

Comment: 1. In the future, please avoid using hdparm on USB drives. It can cause severe problems; 2. When you are afraid of malware, you can try to overwrite the whole drive with zeros, 'wipe the drive'. If the drive is still seen as a mass storage device, it can be done with mkusb. You can analyze the problem according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035), and if you are lucky, find a solution.

Comment: This output to the mkusb console: "dd: failed to open '/dev/sdc': Read-only file system
Warning: Unable to open /dev/sdc read-write (Read-only file system)." makes me think that the USB pendrive might be 'gridlocked', damaged beyond repair. But there are still things to do: The link in my previous comment has a list of tips, that you can try when the drive is read-only: mechanical switch, reboot, disconnect other USB devices, try other USB ports, try another computer, try another operating system. If still no luck, your USB pendrive is probably damaged beyond repair.