# Slow file transfer

Tags: kubuntu, files

I am transferring over 60 GB worth of files to a Lenovo EMC NAS, and if I use dolphin to do this I get desktop lockups and dolphin freezing and if I wate a whial eventually a file about 600 MB will transfer I do see the interface show up that its transferring however it shows finished way before it closes out and actually registers as finished. I'm now trying to use Konsole doing a move of every .7z file in it and each file is taking an extreamly long time. command used was ( mv -f -v /home/zip/Games/Sega-Dreamcast/* /home/zip/Mounts/ZIPNAS/Games/Sega-Dreamcast )

its working but geez its slow and I have more Folders with Gigs of data to move a total of about 2 TB . Help

My systems doesn't even show its being stressed. 27.4 registered GiB of ram and only using 3.5 , swop is using 2.8 MiB I have 8.0GiB of space for swop, network card also only using like a few KiB/s not even close to any limit available , CPU is around 7% sometimes jumps to 30%

I'm still new to Kubuntu / Linux Im a Windows SysAdmin who had made the switch about 9 months ago to using Linux I am one of Two at work who use it and This is for my personal computer sins I also made the switch at home.

Operating System: Kubuntu 21.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.21.4
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.80.0
Qt Version: 5.15.2
Kernel Version: 5.15.12-xanmod1
OS Type: 64-bit
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 4 × Intel® Core™ i5-3475S CPU @ 2.90GHz
Memory: 27.4 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Radeon RX 5500 XT

I am moving from a local main drive to a Mounted NAS

below is what I use in my /etc/fstab to mount at bootup.
//192.168.0.113/Games  /home/zip/Mounts/ZIPNAS/Games  cifs  guest,uid=zip,iocharset=utf8  0  0

Comment: The speed is more to do with your LAN card and peripherals, so unless you are old-skool serial cable you are stuck with a VERY long file transfer. Software depends a lot on RAM for this type of process and that might be the cause of the software crashes. If you are competent you can try the "The Command-Line Way" option listed here but read it and check it severalk times before you execute ANY commands cause you can wipe your whole disk and never get it back. https://askubuntu.com/questions/22381/how-to-format-a-usb-flash-drive

Comment: my issue there is that when I do the same thing but to another mounted drive that is on my network its nice and fast and closes a few seconds after the move shows as done with no lockup.

Comment: I am thinking this might be a limitation on the NAS I just did a over 17 GB file transfer wich had multiple files in the transfer from one Mounted Drive wich is shared on my Netgear NightHawk router to a windows 7 Shared drive and it took about 8 to 10 min with almost no wait after the file move was done using the dolphin interface.

Comment: What disk models are in your NAS?  Those using Shingled Magnetic Recording (SMR) are notorious for being slow writers.  You might have to dig a bit, since the vendors don't necessarily make this fact easy to find.  If the disk comes with a disclaimer "Not suitable for backup" that might be an indirect way of saying it writes too slowly to be useful for large amounts of data.

Comment: I have two raid0 volumes one with WD reds and one with Segate Iron wolf's my NAS is currently not leting me log into it during this transfer or its taking forever to let me into the web interface so not sure wich volume has wich type of drives but its one of the two I just listed