# How to erase device connected through usb in terminal

Tags: nvidia, unity, 22.04

Would you explain how to erase data from device connected through USB in terminal

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `lsusb` before AND after plugging in the device you wish to erase

Comment: Did you check this https://askubuntu.com/questions/22381/how-to-format-a-usb-flash-drive ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a USB flash drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22381/how-to-format-a-usb-flash-drive)

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu / Linux doesn't make a difference between a built-in drive or an external drive, e.g. a USB pen drive.

Open a terminal, navigate to the drive (usually mounted under **/media/your_user_name** and use either the `rm` command to delete single files or `rm -r directory_name` to delete a directory recursively. Or use one of the [mkfs](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/de/man8/mkfs.8.html) commands (e.g. [mkfs.fat](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/mkfs.msdos.8.html)) for formatting the drive. Remember that for the latter the stick has to be not mounted.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! I think the OP was asking how to erase a device, not how to remove a file or directory from said device, or place a filesystem on it it for that matter.